# List all text files present on SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am using the following code to list down all the files present on the SD card. However I just want to list down all the text files can some body tell me how to add a file filter. Similarly I need to fetch the image files as well. Following is my code:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

Comment: If you need to scan recursively subfolders as well, this can be done using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.endsWith()` method from **Java String Class** to check File Extension from file path.

**Method:**

```
public boolean endsWith(String suffix)
```

Your Code something like,

```
private List<String> ReadSDCard()
{
     //It have to be matched with the directory in SDCard
     File f = new File("your path");

     File[] files=f.listFiles();

     for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
     {
      File file = files[i];
      /*It's assumed that all file in the path are in supported type*/
      String filePath = file.getPath();
      if(filePath.endsWith(".txt")) // Condition to check .txt file extension
      tFileList.add(filePath);
     }
 return tFileList;
}
```

Comment: This just checks the extension, not the actual file type. I can rename an image file to .txt and have this code accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FilenameFilter` Interface to Shortlist all TextFiles are any related files to an Array. You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353213/1649309) here to shortlist only image files from SD card.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

String extension=FilenameUtils.getExtension(filepath);
```