# How to Filter .txt file from the sdcard

Tags: android

I want to list of the Text file in Listview and Select .txt file path get from the sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void scandir(File dir) {
    String txtPattern = ".txt";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                scandir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
              if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(txtPattern)){
                                  //Do what ever u want

              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make a call like this:

```
scandir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

**Reference :**

[Android List documents with Specific extension from SD Card](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/android-list-documents-with-specific-extension-from-sd-card/)

Comment: Thanks.But walkdir is a Method.

Comment: @patel change `walkdir` with `scandir`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.endsWith()` method from **Java String Class** to check File Extension from file path.

you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374122/1265724)

```
(another option)
```

You can use `FilenameFilter` Interface to Shortlist all TextFiles are any related files to an Array. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374122/1265724) here to shortlist only image files from SD card.